# What are the red vertices in the UV Editor and how do they affect my unwrap?

Tags: modeling, uv

[image: side by side view of the UV Unwrap and Smart UV Project showing the unwrapping problem.]

UVs on this simple model are pretty messed up and I can't figure out what has happened, does this look familiar?

What are those red highlighted verts?

Note: I have successfully textured other models with no trouble making appropriate seams + unwrapping, Just seems to be a problem with this particular model. Assume I have borked it somehow while editing.

- What I have tried: Thinking it may be that some surfaces are
  duplicated and lying on top of each other, I have merged verts by
  distance.
- Deleted some faces to see if they are connected.
- Added seams, makes little difference.
- Checked that normals are the right way round.

Any ideas welcome.

.blend file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wy0fo09s6336y9r/pugHead.blend?dl=1):

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There don't appear to be any seams marked on the model, so I'm amazed that either unwrap or smart unwrap have unwrapped at all.

The red vertices are pinned. Because they're pinned, you are seeing the UV Unwraps that you are. You need to select all of the Red marked vertices with <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd> in the UV Editor and unpin with <kbd>ALT</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd>.

Once you've done that you should be able to work as normal.